# MomentJS isSameOrAfter

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I'm currently trying to switch a status to `active` if the end date of a plan is the same as or after today's date. This is what I currently have:

```
        const today = moment();
        const planEndDate = moment(value);
        let content;
        if (planEndDate.isSameOrAfter(today)) {
            content = renderNotification('info', 'active');
        } else {
            content = renderNotification('warning', 'inactive');
        }
```

This is the value of `planEndDate: Tue Mar 28 2023 11:00:00 GMT+1100 (Australian Eastern Daylight Time)`.

And this is the value of `today: Tue Mar 28 2023 15:03:04 GMT+1100 (Australian Eastern Daylight Time)`

I'm trying to figure out why I'm getting an `inactive` status for my data when I'm expecting it to be `active` when using the `isSameOrAfter` method.

Comment: your planEndDate is before today, so inactive is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compare the day, then you need to add the granularity

```
  const today = moment();
    const planEndDate = moment(value);
    let content;
    if (planEndDate.isSameOrAfter(today, 'day')) { //<--- here
        content = renderNotification('info', 'active');
    } else {
        content = renderNotification('warning', 'inactive');
    }
```

Else your current code is currently compared by the milliseconds and "inactive" is correct.

Your below planEndDate is **before** today if comparing the milliseconds.

> planEndDate: Tue Mar 28 2023 11:00:00 GMT+1100 (Australian Eastern
> Daylight Time).
>
> And this is the value of today: Tue Mar 28 2023 15:03:04 GMT+1100
> (Australian Eastern Daylight Time)

[You May Not Need Moment](https://github.com/you-dont-need/You-Dont-Need-Momentjs)

Using [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/v2.29.3/docs/isToday)

```
  var isAfter = require('date-fns/isAfter')
  var isToday = require('date-fns/isToday')

  const today = new Date();
  const planEndDate = new Date(value)

  if (isAfter(today, planEndDate) || isToday(planEndDate)) {
     content = renderNotification('info', 'active');
  } else {
     content = renderNotification('warning', 'inactive');
  }
```

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To use moment.js's `isSameOrAfter`, the date should be in format of `moment(YYYY-MM-DD)`

so first convert it to that format

```
const today = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        let planEndDate = moment(value).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        let content;
        if (moment(planEndDate).isSameOrAfter(today)) {
            content = renderNotification('info', 'active');
        } else {
            content = renderNotification('warning', 'inactive');
        }
```

Comment: I'm getting this error `planEndDate.isSameOrAfter is not a function`

Comment: what is the value for ```planEndDate```  before converting it to ```moment``` date?

Comment: This is the value for `planEndDate`, `2023-03-28`

Comment: By puttin ```value = "2023-03-28"``` I am getting the status as active

Comment: In your suggested code above, is having `moment` in front of `planEndDate` necessary? Aren't you already performing it when assigning `moment(value).format('YYYY-MM-DD')`?

Comment: Yes it is necessary to put ```moment(planEndDate)``` otherwise you will get error ```planEndDate.isSameOrAfter is not a function```

Comment: you can read the docs [here](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/05-query/05-is-same-or-after/)

Comment: using moment() is sufficient as isSameOrAfter accepts `Moment|String|Number|Date|Array`, converting to YYYY-MM-DD is not necessary

Answer (score 0):

Switched up the logic behind how a status is being determined and it works fine without usage of the `isSameOrAfter` method.

```
        const today = moment.utc();
        const planEndDate = moment.utc(value);
        let content;
        if (today.isAfter(planEndDate, 'day')) {
            content = renderNotification('warning', 'inactive');
        } else {
            content = renderNotification('info', 'active');
        }
```